# python -m spyder_kernels.console errors out with "cannot import name 'write_connection_file' from 'jupyter_client'"

Tags: python-3.x, spyder, jupyter-lab

While trying to launch a Launch a Spyder kernel on ssh server, it errors out with the following error:

```
bash-4.2$ python3 -m spyder_kernels.console
/home/sachingodishela/python-build/3.10.6/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_client/__init__.py:23: UserWarning: Could not import submodules
  warnings.warn("Could not import submodules")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sachingodishela/python-build/3.10.6/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/home/sachingodishela/python-build/3.10.6/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/sachingodishela/python-build/3.10.6/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spyder_kernels/console/__main__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from spyder_kernels.console import start
  File "/home/sachingodishela/python-build/3.10.6/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spyder_kernels/console/start.py", line 21, in <module>
    import ipykernel
  File "/home/sachingodishela/python-build/3.10.6/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .connect import *  # noqa
  File "/home/sachingodishela/python-build/3.10.6/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/connect.py", line 12, in <module>
    from jupyter_client import write_connection_file
ImportError: cannot import name 'write_connection_file' from 'jupyter_client' (/home/sachingodishela/python-build/3.10.6/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_client/__init__.py)
```

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please run `python3 -m pip install -U jupyter_client` to see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: What spyder-kernels, ipykernel and jupyter_client version are you using? Seems like a similar traceback was submitted as an issue in the ipykernel repo: https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/issues/967

Comment: @CarlosCordoba - Tried that, didn't fix.

Comment: @DanielAlthviz - Went through that github issue, didn't find a solution that works for linux.

Comment: @SachinGodishela, I think it's better for you to install Anaconda/Miniconda and use Spyder from it. That shouldn't show this error.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Carlos, will try and let you know.